# How to load child form before closing the parent without closing them both

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i'm using visual studio 2017 for a certain project

How to load child form before closing the parent without closing them both

Doing this just closes the application without loading the next form:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

edit: question rephrase

Comment: what is the aim of this? what problem do you try to solve?

Comment: I think her question is: How to load child form before closing the parent without closing them both?

Comment: "current" form is main form? So, closing main form closes app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application is closed due to `Application.Run(new Form1())` in `Programm.cs`.

This is a default template for winforms application which assumed you will work with just one (main) form where closing it will terminate application.

I assume you are only calling your forms parent/child, but they are not MDI, nor you are setting [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner) property. Rather two forms where second is displayed conditionally (when the right button is clicked). This condition can be passed via `DialogResult`.

Change your `Main` method to something like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // Application.Run(new Form1()); - don't use this anymore

    var form1 = new Form1();
    if(form1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.XXX)
        (new Form2()).ShowDialog();
}
```

And button click event to:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => DialogResult.XXX;
```

This will close the form and return specified value.

You have to [choose return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult) yourself, if there are no other `OK` is ok.

Comment: no form is running after application.run is commented, even after creating var form1

Comment: @dds998, do you have `form1.ShowDialog()` and `form1` is not displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand your point of not "Using hide" because is the best way to do this...

If you don't want to use Hide you can use Visible and set it to false... Something like this:

```
this.Visible = false;
var form2 = new asas();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
form2.Show();
```

**EDIT:**

You've edited your question, and don't refer anything about hide..

You can do something like this:

```
this.Hide();
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
form2.Show();
```

That's definitely the best way to do this.. Show other form and close the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to use the `Form1.Hide();`
If you want to do that, you could do this in your `Program.cs`:

After the `Application.Run(new Form1());` add this:

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

By doing this, when you close the `Form1`, the `Form2` will be initiated.

To close the `Form1`, just do this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Hope this can help.

Edit:
I read your edit. Probably the best solution is Mikev's answer.